# execution expired with Vertical Response API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have integrated Vertical Response API in my application that is using Ruby on Rails.

I am facing an issue while appending members of list to VR API using 
`vr_obj_new.appendFileToList(sid, lid, csv_data)`

Whenever I call this method, I receive “Execution Expired” error. I tried to upload a list containing around 100,000 records. As the CSV file was huge so I sent multiple CSV file containing chunks of 20000, 10000 and even 5000 records but I am still getting the same error. One major finding that I got is that it is working fine on my DEV environment while giving this error on Production environment. You can find more on error details in the attached text file.

As per I analyzed, this seems to be an issue of `HTTPClient` Timeout on production for which I have set the conditions as:

```
client = HTTPClient.new
client.receive_timeout = 40000
```

But it didn’t work as well.

The exact error is as follows:

```
execution expired
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:43:in `fill_rbuff'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/buffering.rb:107:in `gets'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:352:in `gets'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:879:in `parse_header'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:131:in `timeout'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:875:in `parse_header'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:858:in `read_header'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:667:in `get_header'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1137:in `do_get_header'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1086:in `do_get_block'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:887:in `do_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:981:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:886:in `do_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:774:in `request'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient.rb:684:in `post'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/streamHandler.rb:238:in `send_post'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/streamHandler.rb:172:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:179:in `route'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:143:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/driver.rb:181:in `call'
(eval):6:in `appendFileToList'
./lib/vertical_response.rb:102:in `appendFileToList'
/ebs/data/www/Whelan-Project-Manager/app/models/email.rb:74:in `append_list_to_vr'
/ebs/data/www/Whelan-Project-Manager/app/models/email.rb:71:in `each'
/ebs/data/www/Whelan-Project-Manager/app/models/email.rb:71:in `append_list_to_vr'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:20:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:20:in `perform'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job_without_newrelic_transaction_trace'
(eval):3:in `invoke_job'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:253:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.0/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.3.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:248:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
(eval):2:in `invoke_job'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in `work_off'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:104:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:83:in `run_process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:255:in `start_proc'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:82:in `call_as_daemon'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259:in `start_proc'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:159:in `start_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `fork'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `start_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:157:in `start_all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `run_proc'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `run_process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:75:in `daemonize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in `times'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in `daemonize'
script/delayed_job:5
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved now. It was due to clash of emails when using the Vertical Response API. Let me to try to explain.

As I was using the Partner API of Vertical Response (VR) which uses a sub account (based on Impersonate User field) to perform things like Login, CreateList, CreateEmail, etc. so for logging in into VR it requires a Main login email (username) and Impersonate User email.

The issue was there when I keep same values of Main login email and Impersonate user email in VR Login method. So when using VR Partner API we should keep separate values of both emails. This will resolve the issue.